# Twitter API Get mentions

Tags: delphi, twitter, twitter-oauth

Im having loads of issues with the Twitter API and GET. Hopefully someone can point out my mistake of help me in the correct direction. I got the POST correct for posting statusses, but i want to get the users mentions, but Im receiving "Could not authenticate with OAuth" the whole time.

Below are all my strings and headers as I set / get it. Please help. :)

```
- Generate Base URL -
base=GET&http%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2F1%2Fstatuses%2Fmentions.xml&oauth_consumer_key%3D0RaXE4T4CuMFJHI1jViEQ%26oauth_nonce%3DDGTQVDPXRAYASJJFJLJF%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1309954505%26oauth_token%3D298006718-8yTikfcuvQ3Xq1ZGuykhkxK2wY0ZAOxcI0jesRxd%26oauth_version%3D1.0
----------------------------------
- Build Signature -
SignKey=ey75K0x7bgyI4BwwG5mn7vLVNQiyphJo9MMT8t6bj0&Syk7tpizLGSo2xvJ9Q8Y1G318eKO8QXvPGWoOpdXWw
Signature=Q844NOw7T0oq8tNQkdR/6ez6Z8s=
----------------------------------
- Request twit Start -
postvars=
url=http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/mentions.xml
----------------------------------
- Socket Before Header Send -
GET /1/statuses/mentions.xml HTTP/1.0
Accept: */*
Referer: http://eden.fm
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; ICS)
Host: api.twitter.com
Authorization: OAuth oauth_nonce="DGTQVDPXRAYASJJFJLJF", oauth_callback="oob", oauth_token="298006718-8yTikfcuvQ3Xq1ZGuykhkxK2wY0ZAOxcI0jesRxd", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1309954505", oauth_consumer_key="0RaXE4T4CuMFJHI1jViEQ", oauth_signature="Q844NOw7T0oq8tNQkdR%2F6ez6Z8s%3D", oauth_version="1.0"

----------------------------------
- Socket Header End -
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Wed, 06 Jul 2011 12:16:11 GMT
Server: hi
Status: 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: OAuth realm="http://api.twitter.com"
X-Runtime: 0.00899
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 152
Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=1800
Set-Cookie: k=41.133.180.120.1309954571265496; path=/; expires=Wed, 13-Jul-11 12:16:11 GMT; domain=.twitter.com
Set-Cookie: guest_id=v1%3A130995457172572573; domain=.twitter.com; path=/; expires=Sat, 06 Jul 2013 00:16:11 GMT
Set-Cookie: original_referer=ojItV1ByhTzWh74Jc1NQEw%3D%3D; path=/
Set-Cookie: _twitter_sess=BAh7CDoPY3JlYXRlZF9hdGwrCNR9YP8wAToHaWQiJTQzZGVmMTE3YTI5ZjEz%250AOGYzZWEwYjlmNTRlM2I3MzA2IgpmbGFzaElDOidBY3Rpb25Db250cm9sbGVy%250AOjpGbGFzaDo6Rmxhc2hIYXNoewAGOgpAdXNlZHsA--dd24ddb28d1207c2ebf479e57b6f9edb82553bbe; domain=.twitter.com; path=/; HttpOnly
Expires: Wed, 06 Jul 2011 12:46:11 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Connection: close

----------------------------------
- Request Done Socket DocEnd -
result=
status code=401
headers=HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Wed, 06 Jul 2011 12:16:11 GMT
Server: hi
Status: 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: OAuth realm="http://api.twitter.com"
X-Runtime: 0.00899
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 152
Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=1800
Set-Cookie: k=41.133.180.120.1309954571265496; path=/; expires=Wed, 13-Jul-11 12:16:11 GMT; domain=.twitter.com
Set-Cookie: guest_id=v1%3A130995457172572573; domain=.twitter.com; path=/; expires=Sat, 06 Jul 2013 00:16:11 GMT
Set-Cookie: original_referer=ojItV1ByhTzWh74Jc1NQEw%3D%3D; path=/
Set-Cookie: _twitter_sess=BAh7CDoPY3JlYXRlZF9hdGwrCNR9YP8wAToHaWQiJTQzZGVmMTE3YTI5ZjEz%250AOGYzZWEwYjlmNTRlM2I3MzA2IgpmbGFzaElDOidBY3Rpb25Db250cm9sbGVy%250AOjpGbGFzaDo6Rmxhc2hIYXNoewAGOgpAdXNlZHsA--dd24ddb28d1207c2ebf479e57b6f9edb82553bbe; domain=.twitter.com; path=/; HttpOnly
Expires: Wed, 06 Jul 2011 12:46:11 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Connection: close

----------------------------------
result=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hash>
  <error>Could not authenticate with OAuth.</error>
  <request>/1/statuses/mentions.xml</request>
</hash>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not take a look at my open source [TTwitter library](http://www.simonjstuart.com/delphi-stuff/ttwitter/)? Even though this version of the project is now depreciated (I've rolled TTwitter into a larger project to develop more social networking components) it'll still point you in the right direction :)